# Reverse sigmoid function in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sigmoid

How can I create a reverse sigmoid function? I have created the following one but am not getting the desired output.

```
def sigmoid(x):
  return - (1 / (1 + math.exp(0.5*x)))

x= np.linspace(0,5,100)
y = np.vectorize(sigmoid)
plt.plot(x,y(x))
```

Please notice the x range should be between 0 -5

UPDATE :

I am looking for the following shape

[image]

Comment: Wait, so do you want the reverse function of `sigmoid(x)`? I'm not too familiary with `np`, but what if you plotted `(y(x), x)`?

Comment: . I want to reverse a sigmoid .. thats my approch ( which seems not right I have added - minus to do that )

Comment: Use `-x`? Hard to give an answer without knowing what "reverse" means.

Comment: take a look at the update

Comment: Like, you want some `g(x)` such that `sigmoid(g(x)) == x` holds true for all x?

Comment: From the plot, OP wants `g(x) = sigmoid(-x)`.

Comment: How can I get it

Comment: Just add x = -x

Comment: What do you mean the x range should be between 0 and 5? The domain of a sigmoid is the whole real line, so if you reverse it, it will still be the whole real line.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to invert the `x` axis, you want a function such that `g(x) = sigmoid(-x)`, your definition should be:

```py
def rev_sigmoid(x):
  return (1 / (1 + math.exp(0.5*x)))

x= np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y = np.vectorize(rev_sigmoid)
plt.plot(x,y(x))
```

Comment: I have managed it almost . thanks though

Comment: @AnonymousScientificUser: what do you mean with "but in the x constain between 0-5"?